# Как у view элемента Spinner изменить цвет треугольника?

Tags: android, view, style, android-spinner, android-style

Как у view элемента Spinner изменить цвет треугольника ? Просто у меня он белый и сливается с фоном

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Треугольник у спиннера является частью background:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Измените сам Background

Comment: В api 21 и больше,spinner совсем другой

Comment: @Fasd, ну покажите его

Comment: @Fasd Какая разница, какого он вида в разных API, ответ один и тот же - измените бэкграунд виджета на тот, который вам подходит. А вообще нужно тему Light использовать, раз фон белый.